# Fokker Plank EQUATION

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I would be grateful if you let me know an application of Fokker plank equation in a financial market or introduce a related paper to me.
For example, when the price of stocks in our market satisfiy the Black- Scholes model then the solution of the following
boundary value problem in the domain $[0, T] \times \mathbb R^{+}$ shows the only pricing function.

$$F_t(t, s) + rs F_s(t, s) +\frac{1}{2}s^{2} \sigma^{2}(t, s)F_{ss}(t, s) − rF(t, s) = 0, \ \ F(T, s) = Φ(s).$$

But I can't interpret the solution of the Fokker Plank equation for Black Scholes model

$$dX_t = α X_t dt + σ X_t dW_t.$$

In fact I can't understand what the solution shows?

Comment: The Fokker-Plank equation is [the Black-Scholes equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation) when F is interpreted as the price of an option and s as the price of the underlying stock.